# Transiting through UK Manchester Terminal 1 Visa?

Tags: transit-visas

I am flying from the USA to Turkey with a Turkish passport. I checked the UK "do i need a visa guide", it asks the question if I will go through UK Borders Control, if I will not I will not need a transit visa but if I will I need to get a visa. My experience with other airports is that you don't leave the terminal building ( Amsterdam )so you never pass through the border control.

The thing that bothers me is that I have non-connecting flights with no luggage. Both airlines operate in Terminal 1 in Manchester Airport.

1 ) Will I pass through UK customs ? 
2 ) Will I pass through UK immigration ?

Anybody had experience with Manchester Airport ?

Comment: You won't need to pass through UK immigration but the first airline won't know that, if the flights are not on one PNR. Turkish may deny you bordering based on that.

Comment: This isn't a Problem. Why? Because having a valid US visa not only allows him to Transit airside visa-free, but also *landside*, i.e. enter the UK and remain until 23:59 the next day

Answer (score 3):

Airside Transit (i.e. changing flights without having to enter the UK) is possible at the Heathrow, Gatwick and Manchester Airports (regardless of terminal changes).

I assume you're a Turkish citizen, and they normally Need a visa even for changing flights (a so-called direct airside Transit visa, or DATV for short). However, you have a US visa which is a valid Substitute for this.

So, you don't Need to clear Immigration, and since you have a US visa, don't Need a British DATV

And by the way, even if you did Need to clear Immigration, you could do so without a visa and stay until 23:59 the next day